# missing USDT transaction in Copay or Bitpay Wallets

Tags: copay, omni, tether

I have a missing transaction, a guy sent me <strike>a bitcoins</strike> *USDT*, on his side we can see the money went out and the transaction is confirmed, on my side the money are not at my wallet, what I can do, here is the hash URL:

https://omniexplorer.info/tx/d39bf8c8ba9ad5311818c2eef20a161d3a8c6c2f64247e6ca479c0fcc3b68a0b

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1Bg2UbR3QgPBsPgSKKBezjKiMEHeURx743

please help,
Deyan

Comment: What wallet software are you using?

Comment: Copay v3.9.2 http://prntscr.com/mg71s2 , thank you

Comment: i just installed BitPay v5.5.0 but its the same, the transaction is not there too :S

Comment: It looks like you were actually sent USDT, not Bitcoin, which are not supported by Copay. You will have to move your keys to a wallet that supports USDT.

Comment: ok but did i lose this money in this case ? , how i can move my keys to another wallet

Comment: thank you guys, I have solved the problem with importing my copay private keys to omniwallet.org as they support USDT and I get my funds available

Answer (score 2):

As Raghav Sood commented

> It looks like you were actually sent USDT, not Bitcoin, which are not supported by Copay. You will have to move your keys to a wallet that supports USDT.